# How can I handling with nested data-parent

Tags: c#, .net, razor, model-view-controller

I want to do a Menu with 3 levels using data-parents do close like that:

```
Menu1
---SubMenu1
------Sub_SubMenu1
------Sub_SubMenu2
---SubMenu2
Menu2
---SubMenu22
------Sub_SubMenu21
------Sub_SubMenu22
---SubMenu22
```

So I have the following sample code (not with full menu):

```
    <div id="Menu1">
       <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#div1">
                    Menu1
        </button>
        <div id="div1" data-parent="Menu1">
          <div id="SubMenu1">
       <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#div1">
                    SubMenu1
        </button>
<div id="submenu1"></div>
       <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu2">
                    SubMenu2
        </button>
<div id="submenu2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My problem is when I open any SubSubMenu And after I open a Menu , SubSubMenu isn't closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sidebar Menu Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<style>
.animate-menu-push {
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease; }
  .animate-menu-push.animate-menu-push-right {
    left: 200px; }
  .animate-menu-push.animate-menu-push-left {
    left: -200px; }

.animate-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease; }

.animate-menu-left {
  left: -200px; }
  .animate-menu-left.animate-menu-open {
    left: 0; }

.animate-menu-right {
  right: -200px; }
  .animate-menu-right.animate-menu-open {
    right: 0; }

.sidebar-menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #222d32; }
  .sidebar-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
    .sidebar-menu > li > a {
      padding: 12px 5px 12px 15px;
      display: block;
      border-left: 3px solid transparent;
      color: #b8c7ce; }
      .sidebar-menu > li > a > .fa {
        width: 20px; }
    .sidebar-menu > li:hover > a, .sidebar-menu > li.active > a {
      color: #fff;
      background: #1e282c;
      border-left-color: #3c8dbc; }
    .sidebar-menu > li .label,
    .sidebar-menu > li .badge {
      margin-top: 3px;
      margin-right: 5px; }
  .sidebar-menu li.sidebar-header {
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #4b646f;
    background: #1a2226; }
  .sidebar-menu li > a > .fa-angle-left {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px; }
  .sidebar-menu li.active > a > .fa-angle-left {
    transform: rotate(-90deg); }
  .sidebar-menu li.active > .sidebar-submenu {
    display: block; }
  .sidebar-menu a {
    color: #b8c7ce;
    text-decoration: none; }
  .sidebar-menu .sidebar-submenu {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin: 0 1px;
    background: #2c3b41; }
    .sidebar-menu .sidebar-submenu .sidebar-submenu {
      padding-left: 20px; }
    .sidebar-menu .sidebar-submenu > li > a {
      padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
      display: block;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #8aa4af; }
      .sidebar-menu .sidebar-submenu > li > a > .fa {
        width: 20px; }
      .sidebar-menu .sidebar-submenu > li > a > .fa-angle-left,
      .sidebar-menu .sidebar-submenu > li > a > .fa-angle-down {
        width: auto; }
    .sidebar-menu .sidebar-submenu > li.active > a, .sidebar-menu .sidebar-submenu > li > a:hover {
      color: #fff; }

.sidebar-menu-rtl {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #222d32; }
  .sidebar-menu-rtl > li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
    .sidebar-menu-rtl > li > a {
      padding: 12px 15px 12px 5px;
      display: block;
      border-left: 3px solid transparent;
      color: #b8c7ce; }
      .sidebar-menu-rtl > li > a > .fa {
        width: 20px; }
    .sidebar-menu-rtl > li:hover > a, .sidebar-menu-rtl > li.active > a {
      color: #fff;
      background: #1e282c;
      border-left-color: #3c8dbc; }
    .sidebar-menu-rtl > li .label,
    .sidebar-menu-rtl > li .badge {
      margin-top: 3px;
      margin-right: 5px; }
  .sidebar-menu-rtl li.sidebar-header {
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #4b646f;
    background: #1a2226; }
  .sidebar-menu-rtl li > a > .fa-angle-left {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px; }
  .sidebar-menu-rtl li.active > a > .fa-angle-left {
    transform: rotate(-90deg); }
  .sidebar-menu-rtl li.active > .sidebar-submenu {
    display: block; }
  .sidebar-menu-rtl a {
    color: #b8c7ce;
    text-decoration: none; }
  .sidebar-menu-rtl .sidebar-submenu {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin: 0 1px;
    background: #2c3b41; }
    .sidebar-menu-rtl .sidebar-submenu .sidebar-submenu {
      padding-right: 20px; }
    .sidebar-menu-rtl .sidebar-submenu > li > a {
      padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
      display: block;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #8aa4af; }
      .sidebar-menu-rtl .sidebar-submenu > li > a > .fa {
        width: 20px; }
      .sidebar-menu-rtl .sidebar-submenu > li > a > .fa-angle-left,
      .sidebar-menu-rtl .sidebar-submenu > li > a > .fa-angle-down {
        width: auto; }
    .sidebar-menu-rtl .sidebar-submenu > li.active > a, .sidebar-menu-rtl .sidebar-submenu > li > a:hover {
      color: #fff; }

</style>
<body>
  <section style="width: 200px">
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
      <li class="sidebar-header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </a>

      </li>



      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span>Multilevel</span>
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
            <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Two</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Two <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
                <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </section>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script> 
  <script>
  $.sidebarMenu = function(menu) {
  var animationSpeed = 300,
    subMenuSelector = '.sidebar-submenu';

  $(menu).on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var checkElement = $this.next();

    if (checkElement.is(subMenuSelector) && checkElement.is(':visible')) {
      checkElement.slideUp(animationSpeed, function() {
        checkElement.removeClass('menu-open');
      });
      checkElement.parent("li").removeClass("active");
    }

    //If the menu is not visible
    else if ((checkElement.is(subMenuSelector)) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      //Get the parent menu
      var parent = $this.parents('ul').first();
      //Close all open menus within the parent
      var ul = parent.find('ul:visible').slideUp(animationSpeed);
      //Remove the menu-open class from the parent
      ul.removeClass('menu-open');
      //Get the parent li
      var parent_li = $this.parent("li");

      //Open the target menu and add the menu-open class
      checkElement.slideDown(animationSpeed, function() {
        //Add the class active to the parent li
        checkElement.addClass('menu-open');
        parent.find('li.active').removeClass('active');
        parent_li.addClass('active');
      });
    }
    //if this isn't a link, prevent the page from being redirected
    if (checkElement.is(subMenuSelector)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}

    $.sidebarMenu($('.sidebar-menu'))
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test it in the "Code snippet" will appear exactly as it appears on smart phones, but the appearance will vary completely [on the desktop](https://jsfiddle.net/husam_ebish/9f0emtqx/)

```js
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    breakpoint: 768,
    format: "multitoggle"
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen li:hover > ul > li {
  height: auto;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 35px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  color: #dddddd;
  background: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right ul ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 17px;
  color: #dddddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  top: 23px;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  top: 23px;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
  background: #262626;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 19px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:after {
  top: 15px;
  right: 13px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 22px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:before {
  top: 12px;
  right: 16px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.select-list {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- MenuMaker Plugin -->
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/menumaker/menumaker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> Menus</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1.1</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Sub_SubMenu 1.1.1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Sub_SubMenu 1.1.2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1.2</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2.1</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Sub_SubMenu 2.1.1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Sub_SubMenu 2.1.2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2.2</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Settings</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```